# Why are my hydrangea flowers dying, but the leaves look OK?

Tags: diagnosis, watering, pruning, shrubs, hydrangea

I bought some Hydrangeas in pots in full flower. They were then left un-watered. They are now suffering from dead flowers but the leaves look OK. It is now August in North Yorkshire. Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Pictures would help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If the leaves look fine, it was probably caused by dehydration. Mine did that recently, as well. Cut the flower heads off, and keep the plant well watered.